# Syntatic Error in code-block

Tags: apache-pig

I encountered this syntatic error I could not solve;

```
grunt> describe x;
x: {id: int,b: {(first: int,second: int)}}

grunt> res = foreach x {f = FLATTEN(b); generate id,f;}
2013-07-22 12:28:53,050 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 11, column 21>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'FLATTEN'
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/basic.html#foreach

Only CROSS, DISTINCT, FILTER, FOREACH, LIMIT, and ORDER BY are allowed in the nested block.

Try

```
res = FOREACH x GENERATE id, FLATTEN(b.(first, second));
```